# How to use swagger without annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am working on a java project which does not use spring boot. I am asked to integrate swagger into my project. I have been searching the internet on how to do it without spring boot, but I have found no clue.

Comment: If you are not using annotations means, what kind of project you are implementing and which technologies you used for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual is the way to go. Luckily, they have a tool! https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-editor/  The other great thing is that Swagger is not Java specific so it can be re-used for other REST implementations in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is just an integration for Swagger. You can also make use of Swagger withtout using Spring Boot.

You can use Swagger core library for getting Swagger to work.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core